# The best practise in API proxy between platforms

Tags: java, api

I have API service that deploy to many server. I want to write an router to access these API services.

Is there any java open source solution about this? It like service registered and discovered?
eg: I access /user?flag=a, it will route the request to /user/ that deploy in A server

Comment: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/processes/the-dark-side-of-best-practices/

Answer (score 2):

That's a complex problem and, of course, it was solved. You could look into Eureka and Zuul from [Netflix OSS](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka?utm_source=service-discovery-in-a-microservices-architecture&utm_medium=blog). It's a production ready and maybe a bit complex solution, however I think it's worth learning more about it.

See some tutorials at spring.io to get started: [Zuul](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/), [Eureka](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/)

Comment: sorry, I don't have full tutorial on how to build the complete solution, but that's a direction to go: microservices, spring cloud, netflix oss

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be Java? Assuming that it's HTTP your services are "speaking", take a look at [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [NGINX](https://nginx.org/).

For Apache HTTP Server there is a [mod](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

For NGINX it's [built-in](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) as far as I know.

With those you can route to backends based on rules and patterns.

Comment: NGINX is one solution, but if i want to monitor these service, register or remove these service,  or limit access times to any of these services, It is have to implement.